# Trigger Azure Data Factory Pipeline from Logic App w/ Parameter

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-logic-apps

Let me preface that I'm a noob to Logic Apps and Data Factory. Anyways, I'm currently working on an integration and one part of it is that I need to trigger a pipeline in Data Factory from Logic Apps. I've successfully done that, the *one* part I can't seem to figure out is how to pass parameters to my pipeline. I've tried altering the JSON under both the "parameters" & "triggers" sections but haven't gotten anything to click so far. The pipeline ends up executing, but only with the default parameters.

Has anybody had any success in doing this yet? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you using the REST API to trigger the Data Factory Pipeline Run ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-create-data-factory-rest-api#create-pipeline-run. It may be useful in your case. The logic app connector does not support parameters  ?

Comment: I may need to play around with that, perhaps using the HTTP action in Logic Apps? Mostly trying to get an idea if I'm actually able to use parameters within the ADF connector, which it sounds like I won't be able to?

Comment: Yeah the Http action should work

Comment: Hi Mike, i manage to do this with a combination of azure function and logic app. So I wrote a function that runs pipeline and with .net SDK you can pass parameters.

Comment: Hi @DraganB, you could add some details / screenprints as an answer as that might be more generally useful than a comment.  Thanks.

Comment: @wBob you can check my answer and see if it fits you :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the body property of the logic app's "Create a pipeline run" action to pass parameters to the pipeline. As always, be careful because not only is this action in preview but I also couldn't find this solution in any MS documentation. I just made an educated guess based on how other similar actions are formatted.

Example:

```
"Run_my_pipeline": {
  "inputs": {
    "host": {
      "connection": {
        "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azuredatafactory']['connectionId']"
      }
    },
    "method": "post",
    "body": {
      "param1": "myParamValue",
      "param2": "myParamValue"
    },
    "path": "...",
    "queries": {
      "x-ms-api-version": "2017-09-01-preview"
    },
    "authentication": "@parameters('$authentication')"
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that, since this answer, the Create A Pipeline Run action has added an out of the box parameter named "parameters". That parameters parameter translates to the same body object that I mentioned above. So, this answer is still valid, although, you can now add the body object from the portal view. For the record, this action is still in preview.

Answer (score 1):

as I said in the comment I create a workaround with azure functions. Azure functions and logic app work well together. 
On this link you can see how to create and manage pipelines with .net 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-create-data-factory-dot-net

If you already have ADF and pipeline, you just want to run it (with pipelines) then you can just

```
Dictionary<string, object> parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>
       {
           {"BoxSerialNumbers", req.BoxSerialNumbers},
           {"StartDate", req.StartDate },
           {"EndDate",req.EndDate },
           {"Recipient", req.Recipient }
       };//this is how you add initialaze parameters

        var client = Authenticate(); //Authentication with azure
        log.Info("Creating.");
        CreateRunResponse runResponse = client.Pipelines.CreateRun(resourceGroup, dataFactoryName, "pipeline1", parameters);//run pipeline, you can do this async (it's better)
        log.Info("Created.");
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage();
        if (client.PipelineRuns.Get(resourceGroup, dataFactoryName, runResponse.RunId).Status.Equals("InProgress"))
        {
            response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Content = new StringContent(runResponse.RunId, Encoding.UTF8)
            };
        }
        else
        {
            response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
            {
                Content = new StringContent("Pipeline didn't started", Encoding.UTF8)//just some validation for function
            };
        }
        return response;                                               


    public static DataFactoryManagementClient Authenticate()
    {
        var context = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/" + tenantID);
        ClientCredential cc = new ClientCredential(applicationID, authenticationKey);
        AuthenticationResult result = context.AcquireTokenAsync("https://management.azure.com/", cc).Result;
        ServiceClientCredentials cred = new TokenCredentials(result.AccessToken);
        return new DataFactoryManagementClient(cred) { SubscriptionId = subscriptionID };
    }
```

So in the request, you can pass your parameters from a logic app, with runId you can check status. Then in logic app just simple HTTP request to call this function. Hope this help someone.

Comment: Interesting approach - I have upvoted.  NB Microsoft have just posted (11th May 2018) in the [Logic Apps feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps/suggestions/18176632-action-to-run-data-factory-pipeline) site that an action to run Data Factory pipeline natively from Logic Apps has reached Completed status.  Watch out for it appearing in the product soon I would guess!

Comment: @wBob this way i manage to pass parameters from our web application to data factory and u sql script. 
Also, it's strange there is no connector to u sql (ok you can manage this also with .net but...).
In logic app its still in preview, i believe they will change this.

Answer (score 1):

I used DraganB's solution but the call signature on

```
CreateRunResponse runResponse = client.Pipelines.CreateRun(resourceGroup, dataFactoryName, "pipeline1", parameters);
```

has changed.  Minor edits make this work perfectly:

```
CreateRunResponse runResponse = client.Pipelines.CreateRun(resourceGroup, dataFactoryName, "pipeline1", parameters: parameters);
```

Here's the function for anyone that needs it.

```
[FunctionName("DatafactoryShim")]
    public async static Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post")]
        HttpRequestMessage req,
        ExecutionContext context,
        TraceWriter log
    )
    {
        string messageBody = await req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        BlobToDatalakeFactoryParameters postValues = JsonHelper.ToClass<BlobToDatalakeFactoryParameters>(messageBody);

        Dictionary<string, object> parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            {"blobContainer", postValues.BlobContainer},
            {"blobFolder", postValues.BlobFolder },
            {"relativeDatalakeFolder", postValues.RelativeDatalakeFolder },
            {"modelType", postValues.ModelType }

        }; //this is how you add initialaze parameters

        var client = Authenticate(); //Authentication with azure

        string resourceGroup = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["resourceGroup"];
        string dataFactoryName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["dataFactoryName"];
        string pipelineName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["pipelineName"];

        Console.WriteLine("Creating pipeline run...");
        CreateRunResponse runResponse = client.Pipelines.CreateRunWithHttpMessagesAsync(
            resourceGroup,
            dataFactoryName,
            pipelineName,
            parameters: parameters).Result.Body;
        Console.WriteLine("Pipeline run ID: " + runResponse.RunId);

        var response = new HttpResponseMessage();

        if (client.PipelineRuns.Get(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["resourceGroup"],
            ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["dataFactoryName"], runResponse.RunId).Status.Equals("InProgress"))
        {
            response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Content = new StringContent(runResponse.RunId, Encoding.UTF8)
            };
        }
        else
        {
            response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
            {
                Content =
                    new StringContent("Pipeline didn't started", Encoding.UTF8) //just some validation for function
            };
        }

        return response;
    }
```