# file arrival in blob storage trigger data factory pipeline

Tags: file, azure-blob-storage, pipeline, azure-data-factory, eventtrigger

I need to invoke a Data Factory V2 pipeline when a file is placed in a blob container.

I have tried using Powershell to check if the file is present, the issue I have there is that if the file is not there, and tell me its not there, I then place the file in the container and Powershell will still tell me its not there, though perhaps if it reruns the variable will get a fresh value and tell ites there? Maybe there is a way around that? If yes, I can then use the result to invoke the pipeline with the Powershell script. Am I along the right lines here?

Other option will be to write a t-sql query that will give a true/false result if the row condition is met, but I am not sure how I can use this result within/against DFv2. In the IF condition module?

Tried a Logic app but it was kind of useless. It would be great if I could get some suggestions in some ways to trigger the pipeline on the arrival of the file in the blob container, there is more than one way to skin a cat, so open to any and all ideas. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @PWilliams. Why was useless with logic app?

Comment: Hi DraganB, well when I found an action to trigger the pipeline, it had the usual, subscription, data factory name, but what I did get was it asked for a RunID, which is only created when the pipeline runs and is different everytime. I just could not work out what I was supposed to put in there, and there was little help on the net. In the end, I decided to have the function trigger a powershell script via webhook that would invoke the pipeline that way. Regarding Logic apps in general, I've never manged to do what I needed with one, its always missing something. That's just my experience.

Comment: but what I did *not* get (understand) was *why* it asked for a RunID

Comment: you should use create pipeline run action (this will create and run a new instance of the pipeline), in parameters you need to define only a pipeline name. If you want to pass parameters to pipeline from logic app, you should use Azure function with logic app ( see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50124780/trigger-azure-data-factory-pipeline-from-logic-app-w-parameter/50345850?noredirect=1#comment87752825_50345850 ). 
Yes, logic app seems to have their downside but for now they work well to me :)

Answer (score 1):

This is now available as an event trigger with ADF V2 as announced in [this bog post](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/event-trigger-based-scheduling-in-azure-data-factory/) on **June 21, 2018**.

Current documentation on how to set it up is available here: [Create a trigger that runs a pipeline in response to an event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-event-trigger).

From the documentation:

> As soon as the file arrives in your storage location and the corresponding blob is created, this event triggers and runs your Data Factory pipeline. You can create a trigger that responds to a blob creation event, a blob deletion event, or both events, in your Data Factory pipelines.

There is a note to be wary of:

> This integration supports only version 2 Storage accounts (General purpose).

Event triggers can be one, or both of:

- `Microsoft.Storage.BlobCreated`
- `Microsoft.Storage.BlobDeleted`

With firing conditions from the following:

- `blobPathBeginsWith`
- `blobPathEndsWith`

The documentation also provides the following examples of event trigger firing conditions over blobs:

- **Blob path begins with**('/containername/') – Receives events for any blob in the container.
- **Blob path begins with**('/containername/foldername') – Receives events for any blobs in the containername container and foldername folder.
- **Blob path begins with**('/containername/foldername/file.txt') – Receives events for a blob named file.txt in the foldername folder under the containername container.
- **Blob path ends with**('file.txt') – Receives events for a blob named file.txt at any path.
- **Blob path ends with**('/containername/file.txt') – Receives events for a blob named file.txt under container containername.
- **Blob path ends with**('foldername/file.txt') – Receives events for a blob named file.txt in foldername folder under any container.