# Logic Apps - Get Blob Content Using Path

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, azure-logic-apps, azure-blob-storage

I have a event driven logic app (blob event) which reads a block blob using the path and uploads the content to Azure Data Lake. I noticed the logic app is failing with 413 (RequestEntityTooLarge) reading a large file (~6 GB). I understand that logic apps has the limitation of 1024 MB - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azureblob/ but is there any work around to handle this type of situation? The alternative solution I am working on is moving this step to Azure Function and get the content from the blob. Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: are you using eventgrid or a blob trigger in your logic app ?

Comment: Event Grid which monitors for the new blob creation. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the benefit of others who might be looking for a solution of this sort. 
I ended up creating an Azure Function in C# as the my design dynamically parses the Blob Name and creates the ADL structure based on the blob name. I have used chunked memory streaming for reading the blob and writing it to ADL with multi threading for adderssing the Azure Functions time out of 10 minutes.

Comment: is there any way to do this yet?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use an Azure function, I would suggest you to have a look at this at this article:

- [Copy data from Azure Storage Blobs to Data Lake Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-copy-data-azure-storage-blob)

There is a standalone version of the `AdlCopy` tool that you can deploy to your Azure function.

So your logic app will call this function that will run a command to copy the file from blob storage to your data lake factory. I would suggest you to use a powershell function.

Another option would be to use Azure Data Factory to copy file to Data Lake:

- [Copy data to or from Azure Data Lake Store by using Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-data-lake-store)

You can create a job that copy file from blob storage:

- [Copy data to or from Azure Blob storage by using Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-blob-storage)

There is a connector to trigger a data factory run from logic app so you may not need azure function but it seems that there is still some limitations:

- [Trigger Azure Data Factory Pipeline from Logic App w/ Parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50124780/trigger-azure-data-factory-pipeline-from-logic-app-w-parameter)

Comment: I will look into these options, I started with Azure Functions and notice some challenges in terms of the the time taken. (6 GB file takes around 10+ minutes). Thanks for sharing the articles Thomas!! Appreciate it.

Comment: Yeah I would avoid using functions because functionas are billed per GB/sec

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using Azure Files connector:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azurefile/

It is currently in preview, the advantage it has over Blob is that it doesn't have a size limit. The above link includes more information about it.

Comment: Hi Adam, The design is event driven so the logic app listens for the newly created blobs. I don't think Azure Files currently generate an event for any new file creation. Thanks for your input. I edited my question to be clear.